# bundle install FetchError EOFError

Tags: ruby, proxy, bundler

I am on a windows 2007 box using ruby 2.0 and bundler 1.3.5

I have an issuer where by I can install gems just fine using gem install but bundle install consistently yields the following:

```
C:\src\ruby_test>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: EOFError: end of file reached (https://rubygems.
org/gems/rake-10.1.0.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (10.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I am running behind a proxy and am using cntlm to bypass it (using the http_proxy variable). I am at a loss as to why gem installs work but bundler can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that your proxy doesn't support `https://` type communication.

You might want to tweak the header of your `Gemfile` to read:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org/`
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem. I feel so dumb for not noticing the https in my own gemfile. THANK YOU!